# How do I get the Java primitive void class in Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin, reflection, jvm, void

I'm working on a Kotlin JVM library that uses reflection and at a certain point, I have a method that checks if the specified class is `void` (not `Void`).

In Java, it is as simple as comparing with `void.class`, but in Kotlin I have not been able to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: what "void" class in Java are you talking about?

Comment: `void.class` is actually a thing. Which is the same as `Void.TYPE`

Comment: isn't that Void.class ?

Comment: @Stultuske `void.class` and `Void.class` are both valid. Printing them results in different output though. `Void.class` prints `class java.lang.Void`. `void.class` prints simply `void`. `Void.TYPE` prints `void` as well

Comment: @XtremeBaumer `Void.TYPE` worked just fine. I didn't know it existed in java either. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to @XtremeBaumer for pointing out the [Void.TYPE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html#TYPE) attribute that is available in Java and Kotlin, and both of them refer to the `void` class.

Answer (score 0):

To get `KClass` instance write this

```
Void.TYPE.kotlin
```

**EDIT**

```
fun main() {
    println(Void.TYPE.kotlin == Nothing::class)
    println(Nothing::class.java.name)
    println(Nothing::class.javaPrimitiveType?.name)
    println(Void.TYPE.kotlin.java.name)
    println(Void.TYPE.kotlin.javaPrimitiveType?.name)
}
```

Prints however

```
true
java.lang.Void
void
void
void
```

the choice is yours